# Is there any way to set the point marker in front of the axes? (Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}) fails to work

Tags: plotting

I was trying to plot the points in front of the axes but I could not find a solution. I tried "Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}" but it didn't work in ListPlot function. Thanks for sharing your suggestions!

```
 ListPlot[{{1000, 0}, {2000, 1}, {3000, 0}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.1], ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{800, 3100}, {-0.03, 1.3}}, 
 Ticks -> {{1000, 2000, 3000}, {}}, LabelStyle -> Directive[14], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lp = ListPlot[{{1000, 0}, {2000, 1}, {3000, 0}}, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.1], ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{800, 3100}, {-0.03, 1.3}}, 
   Ticks -> {{1000, 2000, 3000}, {}}, LabelStyle -> Directive[14], 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False];
```

#### 1.

Easiest approach is to wrap `lp` with `Show` with the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}`:

```
Show[lp, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

#### 2.

Use the  primitives from `lp` as  [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) in `Show`:

```
Show[lp, Epilog -> lp[[1]]]
```

[image]

#### 3.

Inject the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` using [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[Prepend[#, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}] &, lp, {2}]
```

[image]

#### 4.

Use `Graphics` with the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` using the graphics primitives and options from `lp` (that is, `lp[[1]]` and `lp[[2]]`):

```
Graphics[lp[[1]], Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}, lp[[2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro! Your solution works perfectly!